# Proving that a set is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As far as I know, a vector space is also a subspace of itself. So, here is my question. Is it possible to prove that a set is not a vector space by proving that it does not satisfy the 3 conditions of a subspace? For instance that it does not contain 0.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Instead of the number $0$ it could be the neutral element, if $(V,+)$ doesn't consist of numbers. Take for example $V$ the vector space of real sequences and the subspace of sequences converging to zero.

Comment: What about integers $\mathbb{Z}$? Are they a vector space with the regular addition and multiplication that you know? They certainly have a zero, they're closed under multiplication and they're closed under addition, but...

Comment: But the OP asked what we can conclude if the zero element is *not* contained. Then it is indeed not a vector (sub)space.

Comment: From the way the OP phrased the question with "vector spaces are subspaces of themselves" it makes me think the OP thinks that it is sufficient to ONLY check the subspace criteria, and I think an example where this is not enough is at least good for OP to see. If any vector space axiom is violated (got nothing to do with subspaces) then the set (given the addition and multiplication) is of course not a vector space.

Comment: Yes, this is of course right. I just wanted to justify my remarks above. Given a subset of a vector space (that's the typical homework question), decide whether or not it is a subspace. Then you are done for the case that zero is not contained in the set.

Answer (score 0):

A "vector subspace" $Y$ of a "vector space" $X$ is simply a vector space on its own, with the same operations of $X$, and $Y\subseteq X$. This means that, of course, $X$ is a vector subspace of itself.

Now, how do you define a vector space $(X,+,\cdot)$ (over a field $\mathbb{F}$)? The pair $(X,+)$ should be an abelian group with respect to $+: X^2\to X$ (denoting with "$0$" its identity, so yes, if such element "$0$" does not exist then it cannot be a vector space), endowed with a compatible product $\cdot: \mathbb{F}\times X\to X$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) for the precise axioms).

What you are referring to with "the 3 conditions for a subspace" $Y$ (which, I guess, are non-emptyness and closure under linear combinations) *requires* that you can identify a bigger set $X$ as a vector space. Hence, *if* you know that $X$ is a vector space, then a subset $Y\subseteq X$ is a vector space on its own (with the induced operations) if and only if it satisfies "the 3 conditions". However, if you are not able to identify such vector space $X$, then you can only rely on the very definition of vector space.